# limiting user to only select items on laravel listbox

Tags: laravel, limit

I would like to ask for help, please advise how to solve such problems in laravel

how to make an application like a vehicle ticket application, to limit if there are 5 people on car A, then user can not choose car A in listbox (item listbox carA disable) when booking.

I am confused where to start

I am currently thinking of creating 3 tables

```
users (id, name,car_id, created_at, updated_at) 
cars (id, car_name, created_at, update_at)
```

I am confused what should be done to the controller Thank you very much

thanks to all of you, i can start the first step.
currently

on the controller

```
public function create(){
    $list=MCars::all();

    return view('booking/create')->with('sent_list',$list);
```

}

on the view

```
<select name="car" value="{{ old('car')}}">
@foreach($sent_list as $a)
  <option value="{{$a->id}}">{{$a->car_name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I want only cars that contain users <5 that appear on the view

maybe i should put this somewhere

SELECT DISTINCT cars.id, cars.car_name, COUNT(users.car_id) from cars INNER JOIN users ON cars.id = users.car_id

Comment: We can't help you with a random idea! Show some code, we could help you to solve the code(both syntax and logic).

Comment: yes, sorry about that, now i try a little ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship can be like this:

> **a user `belogsTo` a car and the car `hasMany` users**

So the Car model class should be:

```
..
class Car extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

And the User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
    }
}
```

*Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key. So, here Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the User model is `car_id`.
Access the collection of users by accessing the `users` property.*

```
$users = App\Car::find(1)->users;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    //
}
```

In the `UserController` use:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
echo $user->car->name;
```

This is how the Eloquent works!

Now use the custom logic for limit(5).

To retrieve the number of cars as users:

```
public function getTotalUsersAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Car')->whereUserId($this->user_id)->count();    
}
```

And:

```
if(getTotalUsersAttribute() >= 5) {
    // dismiss this function with an err msg
}
// otherwise add user to car
```

Find similar cases and solution from the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can make the registration for user, user will insert their name(according to your table), but i'll suggest for inserting new column email and password for login system. if they not login, they cant booked cars. they must register and login to booking cars.
2. after user login, the car can be booked, you must create form for it. the code something like this

   ```
   $cars_id = request::get('id');
   $total_passenger  = DB::table('passenger')->WHERE('car_id',$cars_id);
   if(count($data) < 5){
      //do insert data into passenger
   }else{
      //windows alert / whatever
   }
   ```